# Why won't my Windows 7 PC recognize my USB Gaming Headset?

Tags: windows-7, usb, headset

I have an issue which includes my Turtle Beach Gaming Headsets PX3's. Every time I try connect them to the computer but it won't be recognized by the system. My headset is fully charged but will not connect.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We need some more details. Is this the first time you have connected this headset to this computer? Have you installed drivers specific to your headset? What have you tried in order to resolve this?

Comment: Very sorry. So I have used them many times before and have never need to install drivers. My headset has the choice wireless or direct where wireless I have a little device which is connected via usb and that connects my headset or I use a usb cable that is direct and put into a usb port.

Comment: I'd suggest checking the sound properties in `Control Panel` to see if the headset is selected as the playback device.

Comment: Sorry but It doesn't show up

Comment: the headset in preferences sorry\

Comment: That is the problem. Please edit your question to include these details so answers can be specific.

Comment: I am so sorry but I found out what to do through the post you made from turtle beaches website. I set it into wired mode and I was trying to connect it through wireless. I am so sorry but thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Turtle Beach's [support documents](http://support.turtlebeach.com/entry/830517278/), you need to do the following to use the headset in wired mode connected to a PC.

> 1) Power on the PX3 headset.
>
> 2) Insert the USB Mini-B end of cable into the headset and the USB
>   Standard-A end of the cable into your computer.
>
> 3) Double-press the Power button on the headset to enter Wired Mode.
>   (When you double-press, be sure to press the button firmly, but not
>   too quickly; if the double-press is done too quickly or too slowly,
>   your computer will only recognize your headset as the PX3 Charger.)
>   When successful, a double tone will sound and the LED on the headset
>   will change to solid RED.
>
> 4) Go into your computer's sound settings and make sure "PX3 Headset"
>   is set as your playback or output device.

Comment: I have the booklet with me and I know how to do it but when I go to sound preferences on control panel then to microphones, it doesn't show up